# Grid system. How to delete padding

Tags: html, css

I want to delete padding from left&right without p-0. I added class home-posts to every cols and styled it like
display: inline-block;
padding: 0;
But It's not working. What did I wrong ?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 home-posts">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-2 home-posts">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 home-posts" id="home-links">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your CSS.

Comment: `px-0` you should read the doc !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**By using `no-gutters` class**

---

Add just `no-gutters` class to `row`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 home-posts">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-2 home-posts">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 home-posts" id="home-links">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </div>
</div>
```

`no-gutters` class style in bootstrap.

```
.no-gutters {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

This make every col padding in both **right and left** becomes zero

```
.no-gutters > .col, .no-gutters > [class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: but how should I then add myself padding ? It's the same as p-0 . And than I cannot change like media padding

Comment: Now , I add full desciption here. check now

Comment: Can you add padding  for every col.

Comment: .home-posts{padding:0 10px !important; } use to override bootstrap padding